# \emptyset doesn't work with LuaTex + glossaries + unicode-math (bug?)

Tags: luatex, glossaries, unicode-math

The following code doesn't work with LuaTex (I get an "undefined control sequence" error). It works if I either comment out \usepackage{unicode-math} or if I change the glossary name from $\emptyset$ to something else. Is this a bug? How can I fix this because I need all packages.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\newglossaryentry{symb}{name={$\emptyset$}, description={description}}

\begin{document}
$\emptyset$, \gls{symb}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A number, but not all, of the `unicode-math` definitions are performed at `\begin{document}`.  In particular `\emptyset` is defined to be `\varnothing` early on, but the definition of `\varnothing` occurs at the start of the document body.  Moving the definition of the glossary entry out of the preamble circumvents the problem.

Other ways to deal with this include

- issuing `\glsnoexpandfields` before the definition
- adding `\protect` to the glossary entry

  ```
  \newglossaryentry{symb}{name={$\protect\emptyset$}, description={description}}
  ```
- providing a temporary definition of `\varnothing` in the preamble, e.g. `\let\varnothing\relex` just after `\usepackage{unicode-math}`

The first approach suggested by the glossaries author Nicola Talbot is the simplest approach for entries in the preamble.  (According to the documentation it should be unnecessary, as that states that the `name` field is not expanded by default, but your example shows that expansion is occuring.)  egreg suggested the second approach which is good for a one off entry.   The final approach is what I originally suggested; I would not recommend this as a general practice, but it does demonstrate exactly where the problem lies:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\let\varnothing\relax

\usepackage{glossaries}
\newglossaryentry{symb}{name={$\emptyset$}, description={description}}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
$\varnothing$, $\emptyset$, \gls{symb}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: Another strategy is using `$\protect\emptyset$`.

Comment: @egreg Much preferable.

Comment: @user4811 Alternatively, switch off the [field expansions](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:expansion) using `\glsnoexpandfields` (for version 4.0 and above).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Very good.  I have updated my answer to include this.

Comment: @AndrewSwann You're right that the `name` field isn't expanded by default, but the `text` and `first` fields are (and `plural` and `firstplural`) which is what's causing the problem as they pick up their values from the `name` key if unspecified. (This behaviour is maintained for backwards compatibility and originates from the time when the `name` field was written to the external glossary file and so had to be sanitized to protect fragile commands.)